# WordPress - custom img input field that would send <img> to editor

Tags: wordpress

How to create a custom filed, which uses media library image picker.
    
In the WordPress editor.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom img input field" ?

Comment: Simple input filed ? in question you are talking about image input text filed,  i have never listen that before.

Comment: Sorry if sounds confusing.. What i mean is a simple text field where one would enter a img url which would embed the image in wordpress post...

Comment: you are talking about back end admin right ? where admin can do that thing not site user ?

Comment: Yes a custom field in the new post page. Though i would use it in the frontend using the custom field's meta key...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin for creating image picker custom filed. (I will recommend "Advance Custom Field")

just have to install the plugin and create a custom filed of image.

Follow this :

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: It uses the default media popup...i don't want my users to upload images...just wanna add an input field where they post link of the image...

Comment: Select text filed then.

Comment: Okay i m trying it...hope it would be fine to ask for further help if i get stuck.